# problem with let in binding in a predicate in haskell language?

Tags: haskell

i'm newbie in haskell language. i wrote function get list of pairs as input and return list of BMI index:

`calcBMI:: (RealFloat a)=> [(a,a)]->[a]`

`calcBMI xs = [  result | (w,h)<-xs, let bmifunc (w,h)= w/h^2; result =bmifunc (w,h) in result >=25]`

when i save and **:reload** in *ghci*, error: **Not in scope: `result'**
**Failed, modules loaded: none** appear. i think the list comprehension don't know *what is **result***which i have introduced in predicate of list comprehension. Please tell me why? and how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variables defined in `let ... in` is only effective in the expression after `in`. So, you cannot use your `result` in anywhere else. Luckily Haskell list comprehension expression allows you to define variables in it that is referrable anywhere in the expression, by simply adding a `let x = ...` generator. Hence instead of writing

```hs
calcBMI xs =
  [result | (w, h) <- xs,
            let bmifunc (w, h) = w / h ^ 2;
                result = bmifunc (w, h)
             in result >= 25]
```

You can write

```hs
calcBMI xs =
  [result | (w, h) <- xs,
            let bmifunc (w, h) = w / h ^ 2;
                result = bmifunc (w, h),
            result >= 25]
```

and the code will compile.

Comment: And as a stylistic thing, I absolutely would inline the definition of `bmifunc`: `[bmi | (w, h) <- xs, let bmi = w/h^2, bmi >= 25]`.